# Android , display from database to listview error

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-adapter

I have problem with displaying data from db to listview.
Here is code:

DB class:

```
public ArrayList<Task> getTasks(){
    ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_TASKS, null, null, null, null, null, null);


    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Task task = new Task(
                    cursor.getString(1),
                    cursor.getString(3),
                    cursor.getString(2));
            tasks.add(task);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return tasks;
}
```

Task class

```
 public Task(String name, String description, String priority){
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.priority = priority;
}
```

List activity class

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    tasksListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tasksListView);
    myTasks = dbHelper.getTasks();// metoda isto vraća array list

    myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Task>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myTasks);

    tasksListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}
```

I get:
   [Results sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HObhu.png)

MyAdapter values

[Adapter values from debuger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1JEv.png)

How can i display values from  myadapter to listview?

Answer (score 1):

The adapter has no way to understand how to display your `Task` data so you should override `toString` method of your class which may solve your problem:

```
public Task(String name, String description, String priority){
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.priority = priority;

    public String toString()
    {
        return "name: "+name+" description: "+description+" priority: "+ priority;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the official documentation of [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) :

> However the TextView is referenced, it will be filled with the toString() of each object in the array. You can add lists or arrays of custom objects. Override the toString() method of your objects to determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list.

So, you know what to do. Override the `ToString()` method to something like :

```
public String toString()
{
    return "name: "+name;
}
```